# tmux in docker not adjusting for changes in window size when launched via runuser

Tags: bash, docker, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My dev environment is a docker instance running `tmux 3.1c`, usually from within a Windows Terminal. The launch script creates a new user account with the hostname `$USER` and matching `uid`/`gid` values so that if I modify files from within the environment they are correctly permissioned. It launches a shell for the user using the `runuser` command.

This works fine for the most part, but if I launch the instance and tmux, and then adjust the size of the window, my tmux instance doesn't adjust. `stty size` also doesn't update and shows an incorrect value.

This only happens within the docker instance, and if I run tmux on the host itself within Windows Terminal, it's fine. In fact, if I run tmux within a normal docker instance it's fine too, but if I launch as the `$USER` account using `runuser` it breaks.

This might seem complicated but it's the smallest reproducible example I could come up with. If I remove the use of `runuser` and run simply as `root` the terminal adjusts correctly when running tmux. Conversely, if I do use `runuser` but don't launch tmux then the output of `stty size` correctly adjusts as well. So it's something to do with the interaction of docker/runuser/tmux where things are breaking.

Here is the smallest reproducible example I managed to come up with:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  test:
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    hostname: "test"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9.10
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y less sudo tmux

COPY add_user.sh /tmp/add_user.sh
```

**add_user.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=$1
GROUPNAME=$1
USERID=$2
GROUPID=$3

addgroup --gid $GROUPID $GROUPNAME
adduser --uid $USERID --gecos "" --disabled-password --gid $GROUPID $USERNAME
chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUP /home/$USERNAME
```

**launch.sh**

```
USERID=$(id -u ${USER})
GROUPID=$(id -g ${USER})

CMD="/tmp/add_user.sh $USER $USERID $GROUPID && runuser -l $USER -c '/bin/bash'"

docker-compose --file $(dirname $0)/docker-compose.yml run --rm test bash -c "$CMD"
```

**Reproduction steps**

```
docker compose build && ./launch.sh
```

Now open tmux and check the window size:

```
tmux
stty size
```

In my case this produces the following:

```
quant@test:~$ stty size
18 106
```

Now adjust the size of the window. In my case this scrambles the tmux window, moves the cursor to the wrong part of the screen, and `stty size` produces the same output as before:

[image]

exiting tmux and running `stty size` produces the correct result:

```
quant@test:~$ tmux
[exited]
quant@test:~$ stty size
19 69
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

**System details:**

- Tmux version is 3.1c
- Windows terminal is 1.13.11431.0
- Host OS is Windows 10 running a WSL2 instance of Debian Buster

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post a workaround that I found. This is barely an answer since I still don't understand why `runuser` fails, but replacing `runuser -l $USER -c '/bin/bash'` in `launch.sh` with `sudo -u $USER '/bin/bash'` fixes the problem.

So something funky is going on between `runuser` and `tmux`/`docker` but I really don't know what it was...